# Date stored in database and date fetched from database differes

Tags: mysql, angular, date, typeorm

[image]In database, the table-> date column showing the correct date and time.

in database table column :

**2020-08-25 04:00:32.217609**

But when I am fetching the same date, it's showing the exactly 24 hrs old date and time.

fetched from database :

**2020-08-24T16:00:32.217Z**

I think it's about local timezone and also the format is different when fetching. I am trying to understand the issue and then looking for solution.

Note: *I am fetching the data using typeorm queryBuilder.*

Comment: Its not 24 hr, its 12 hrs. So sure it might be time zone. What is the table structure (`show create table {tablename}`)?  Can your orm query builder show what is retreived? (maybe enable the Mysql general query log briefly)?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, in New Zealand?

Comment: @danblack It is actually 24 Hrs as for the database value its showing in the 12 Hrs time and for fetched value it shows in 24hrs time format.
You can see the structure for that column I've just added at top of the post. 

yes I've response of the query and that shows the **2020-08-24T16:00:32.217Z**

Comment: @Schwern : Yes!!

Comment: The column datatype is `DATETIME(6)`. This datatype does not contain timezone info, and no timezone shift is applied to the data implicitly. Retrieve the value using CLI - you must get the value equal to saved one. This may be an effect of client software "service".

Comment: @Akina : What you mean by retrieve values using CLI?

Comment: I mean that you must retrieve values via CLI and check does it is unshifted. If so then timezone shift is performed later - in the connector (I doubt), access library or client retrieving/printing procedures. The problem exists - so the first step is to determine on what stage this timeshift is performed.

Comment: I got to know that, SQL is storing data according to their timezone, while fetching from database is getting the same, the only thing I need to do either change UTC to local timezone or convert the current time zone to UTC to compare the difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same time in different time zones. The first is in your local time zone (New Zealand Standard Time) 12 hours ahead of UTC. The `Z` at the end of the second indicates it is in UTC, 12 hours behind you.

The other difference is in the fractional seconds. Your database is storing in microseconds. Your program is storing in milliseconds, or only displaying milliseconds.

Comment: What to do now :)

Comment: @DLV Use the fetched result. Presumably it's a `Date` object.

Comment: I am using the fetched result only....I didn't get you!!